# How to update my dependency in gerrit review

Tags: git, gerrit

I push a review to gerrit which depends on a review named "xxx".
Right now, "xxx" is updated. How can i pull the dependency into my review with the least merge conflict?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really any way to do it with the 'least merge conflict'.  If there is a conflict, then there is a conflict, and it will be the same no matter what you do.

Assuming the dependency change 'xxx' is still under review, i.e. not merged yet...

Fetch the dependency change, check it out, fetch and cherry pick your change on top of it, and then push back to Gerrit:

```
$ git fetch review refs/changes/xxx && git checkout FETCH_HEAD
$ git fetch review refs/changes/yyy && git cherry-pick FETCH_HEAD
$ git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
```

You should be able to get the exact `fetch` commands to use from the download links under the latest patch set on the change screen on Gerrit.

Comment: Thanks for your help and I now know my problem. In actual, xxx is depended on xx, while my initial review yy is also depended on xx. So when I try to rebase my yy on xxx, also I have to solve duplicate merge conflict. After I use 'rebase -i xxx' command and delete the xx commit in my yy, the problem is solved.